# Shorthand way of generating owned strings

Tags: string, rust, ownership

Given the following struct (in practice, its  bigger than this):

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Parameter {
    name: String,
    value: String,
}
```

If I want to create an instance of this (for tests, etc.):

```
Parameter {
    name: "name".to_string(),
    value: "value".to_string()
}
```

I have to call `to_string` on the end of all my values. This is a bit annoying. Is there a shorthand way of creating an owned string?

Comment: You can use `"name".into()`, that is technically shorter. But I wouldn't worry too much about it. Rust is not about _shortness_ but about _explicitness_. A shorthand syntax would make the allocation less explicit.

Comment: As many things in rust this is needed explicetly. `to_owned`, `String::from` are other options...

Comment: I suggest you implement a constructor `fn new(name: impl Into<String>, value: impl Into<String>) -> Parameter` to create new parameter instances. You can call this constructor with string slices `Parameter::new("name", "value")`, but it will also accept strings.

Comment: FWIW, there has been some [talk](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/3101-reserved_prefixes.md) about extending the syntax to be able to write `String` literals with something like `s"name"`.

Comment: That s"..." syntax would be really great to see in Rust! That or something similar, that is both concise and explicit.

Comment: in practice it's not a big deal

Answer (score 7):

You could always shorten it with a macro:

```
macro_rules! s {
    ($s:expr) => { $s.to_string() }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parameter {
    name: String,
    value: String,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Parameter { name: s!("foo"), value: s!("bar"), });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d57308c718f1bed5af5aeeffa1a96b0)

Comment: There is no need to write a macro when you can write a function, that is both shorter (no `!`) and does not require a macro: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=41f01d14a279b9cfc364d19103284a67.

Comment: A macro is nicer, because A) you can globally import it once and B) it is always inlined and C) it is inlined with minimal compilation overhead. If it is a function you'd A) have to import in every file you use it, B) even with the` [#inline]` attribute there is no guarantee the function is inlined and C) there is a per-crate compilation overhead to cross crate inlining.

Answer (score 0):

The macro by Jmb works fine, but I prefer to use plain functions where possible. (I also prefer post-fix operations over prefix+postfix ones)

So this is the variant I have used:

```rust
pub trait ToStringExt : ToString {
    /// Simply an alias for `.to_string()`.
    fn s(&self) -> String {
        self.to_string()
    }
}
impl<T> ToStringExt for T where T: ToString {}
```

And then to use it:

```rust
use to_string_ext::ToStringExt;

fn main() {
    let my_str: String = "some string".s();
}
```

---

If the only case where you want this shorthand is converting a `&str` into a `String`, then this is a narrower alternative: (which I prefer nowadays)

```rust
pub trait ToOwnedExt where Self : ToOwned {
    /// Simply an alias for `.to_owned()`.
    fn o(&self) -> <Self as ToOwned>::Owned {
        self.to_owned()
    }
}
impl<T: ?Sized> ToOwnedExt for T where T: ToOwned {}
```

And then to use it:

```rust
use to_owned_ext::ToOwnedExt;

fn main() {
    let my_str: String = "some string".o();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using snippets to reduce the pain a little bit.

Using `vscode` and `rust-analyzer`

```json
// settings.json
{
    "rust-analyzer.completion.snippets.custom": {
        "String::from prefix": {
            "prefix": "s",
            "body": "String::from(\"$1\")$0",
            "description": "String::from(\"…\")",
        },
        "String::from postfix": {
            "postfix": "s",
            "body": "String::from(${receiver})",
            "description": "String::from(…)",
        },
    }
}
```